# navigator.pop(context) not "popping" showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter

I have googled how to make showModalBottomSheet go away programmatically and they say to use navigator.pop(context), but this is taking me to the previous screen, not just getting rid of the modal but the entire screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed this by putting Navigator.pop(context) inside the IconButton's onPressed that is inside the modal, before I had the pop reference inside the function that the modal was calling, guess this matters.